# Using forms authentication class for authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an user authentication site. 
I have a login page, "Login.aspx" in which i have provided a login control.
In the web.config,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".AuthenticationCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx"  protection="All" timeout="60" path="/">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="Jack" password="Jerry"/>
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

In the login.aspx.cs page,
I have provided,

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Login1.UserName,Login1.Password))
        {
             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName,true);
            Label1.Text = "Login Successful";
            Login1.InstructionText = "";
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
            Response.Redirect("Success.aspx")

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "You are not an authentic user";
        }


    }
}
```

but however, while execution instead of going to success.aspx 
with the url http://localhost/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSuccess.aspx

Why is this so?

Comment: I don't understand what it's doing. You say "while execution instead of going to success.aspx ..." What is it doing "instead of" that?

Comment: sorry 4 dat....
instead of that it remains in Login.aspx with the above specified url.

Comment: In your above code, now that it's using RedirectFromLoginPage, you should remove the SetAuthCookie and Response.Redirect calls. After you do that, if it's still having the same problem, what do you see when you step through it in the debugger. Does the FormsAuthentication.Authenticate call succeed? If so, does it make it to the RedirectFromLoginPage call? What HTTP traffic do you see (use Fiddler - http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: thank you.. problem is solved  :)

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you explained what solved the problem (plus I'm curious ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the forms auth cookie yourself and redirect correctly based on the ReturnUrl query string parameter,  you should look at the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage method. In your example, it would be:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
```

That method sets the appropriate Forms auth cookie / ticket and then redirects based on the presence or absence of the ReturnUrl parameter. (If absent, it goes to the configured default page.)

Hope this helps,

Donnie

Comment: ya..i did it..and the modified code is given above. but the output remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for tip.. Actually, running into the same problem.